# Split an array cause an error: not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I want to split an array that already have been split.

```
    var string = '2016-08-08,63|2016-08-07,67|2016-08-06,64|2016-08-05,53|2016-08-04,63';
    var array_dt = string.split(',');
    var array_s = array_dt.split('|');
    console.log(array_s);
```

That code returns `TypeError: array_dt.split is not a function`.

I'm guessing that `split()` can not split an array. Have I wrong?

Here's how I want it to look like. For `array_dt`: `2016-08-08,2016-08-07,2016-08-06,2016-08-05,2016-08-04`. For `array_s`: `63,67,64,53,63`. I will use both variables to a chart (line) so I can print out the dates for the numbers. My code is just as example!

How can I accomplish this?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/edgren/wwt6c3jd/)

Comment: An array can't be `split()`, it has no splitting functionality

Comment: Just as I thought. But how can I accomplish that I am after?

Comment: You can split the individual strings produced by `string.split(',')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split on both characters, just use a regular expression

```js
var string = '2016-08-08,63|2016-08-07,67|2016-08-06,64|2016-08-05,53|2016-08-04,63';
var array_dt = string.split(/[,|]/);

console.log(array_dt)
```

This will give you an array with alternating values, if you wanted to split it up you can do

```js
var string = '2016-08-08,63|2016-08-07,67|2016-08-06,64|2016-08-05,53|2016-08-04,63';
var array_dt = string.split(/[,|]/);

var array1 = array_dt.filter( (x,i) => (i%2===0));
var array2 = array_dt.filter( (x,i) => (i%2!==0));

console.log(array1, array2)
```

Or if you want to do everything in one go, you could reduce the values to an object

```js
var string = '2016-08-08,63|2016-08-07,67|2016-08-06,64|2016-08-05,53|2016-08-04,63';

var array = string.split(/[,|]/).reduce(function(a,b,i) {
  return a[i%2===0 ? 'dates' : 'numbers'].push(b), a;
}, {numbers:[], dates:[]});

console.log(array)
```

If performance is important, you'd revert to old-school loops, and two arrays

```js
var string = '2016-08-08,63|2016-08-07,67|2016-08-06,64|2016-08-05,53|2016-08-04,63';

var array = string.split(/[,|]/);
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

for (var i = array.length; i--;) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    array1.push(array[i]);
  } else {
    array2.push(array[i]);
  }
}

console.log(array1, array2)
```

Comment: `split()` can handle regex? Cool! I didn't know that. Thanks for learning me that.

Comment: I choose to accept your anser since it was the shortest and did it job really well! But how's the performance of it? Is it well optimized?

Comment: @ErikEdgren - I added a version for perfomance as well, but they are all performant enough for most use cases, unless it's an extremely large string.

Comment: Ok. Very nice! It will only show 20 dates and numbers as max, so it's not a large string. Many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = '2016-08-08,63|2016-08-07,67|2016-08-06,64|2016-08-05,53|2016-08-04,63';
var array_dt = [];
var array_s = [];
string.split('|').forEach(function(el){
  var temp = el.split(",");
  array_dt.push(temp[0]);
  array_s.push(temp[1]);
});
console.log(array_dt);
console.log(array_s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it one step at a time - split by pipes first, leaving you with items that look like `2016-08-08,63`. Then for each one of those, split by comma, and insert the values into your two output arrays.

```
var string = '2016-08-08,63|2016-08-07,67|2016-08-06,64|2016-08-05,53|2016-08-04,63';

var arr = string.split("|");
var array_dt = [];
var array_s = [];
arr.forEach(function(item) {
    var x = item.split(",");
    array_dt.push(x[0]);
    array_s.push(x[1]);
});
```